# Why is there an error with type never in a function call?

Tags: typescript

tell me why he swears at `never`?

I can't figure out where it comes from?
I see that the problem is in the `agreePrivacy` method, which simply checks that the value is `true`

If I remove this method, the problem will disappear.

if i remove `Omit` and `sendMarketingEmails` field from `interface ISignupRequest` same error...
It seemed to me that everything is simple and clear for a typescript...

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGVgHMQFcAOAShAI64QDOYyA3gLABQyyANgPZagBcyVUoWANyNmEALZxgLHnwHCmyfHAoUA7mygATGWH4ghI5HCxQIEAAr8AbogCePAEZs2LCHBDzmFCCE0BZOCgAawgwAQBRCSkKR2dXd3kAX0ZGUEhYRBRUAFVvKEJcVwpaQ3ZOEB4ACjLuXl0BAEpkAF4APmQnFzcPQyUVdS0qvrUNbTq9LCa2jrjuz2RxSWlkSsWpHQmp9s74noVjUwtrOyqDs1iu9y2Zy73khkYENhAqZFw8gqKeHI-CyhaSgoahUVsDrgBCcHAgB0rn0YAAFgAaXrKEaDFbDAaaCHgrGjWE+LCIlEKNbLVZRFi48mE+HIwxnI7AGwIewrJnXJmkxLyR7PV42FjATRwSC5aAAyqGd7QHgAeTEwDAAB4MNg8ERSOQqEjkAAiby+ALBUIRKkUfWtUkNHgAQSgUDgthV7ls7Tahkq8ocACsIAgwNCQrYKJVZVAmspkA6nS6Q2wYMgwLZ8BBE288q0GoZmNCYFJ0pVKiGIRHPpQANohgC64by1YgthrDRzCjzEnwxdLLXalXo7eYijFCJ4IdJQ6HYkoFGMEB4AAMACQ0EOJZDAYqgIUihcToeJVuCIA)

```
interface ISignupRequest {
  login: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  agreePrivacy: boolean;
  sendMarketingEmails: boolean;
}

interface IUserRules {
  login: (login: string) => boolean;
  password: (password: string) => boolean;
  email: (email: string) => boolean;
  agreePrivacy: (agree: boolean) => boolean;
}

const userRules: IUserRules = {
  login: (login) => !!login.length,
  password: (password) => !!password.length,
  email: (email) => !!email.length,
  agreePrivacy: (agree) => agree,
};

const validateUser = (
  user: Omit<ISignupRequest, "sendMarketingEmails">,
): Array<any> =>
  (Object.keys(user) as Array<keyof typeof user>)
    .filter((key) => !userRules[key](user[key]))
    .map((key) => ({
      path: key,
      message: `${key} is invalid`,
    }));
```

Error in `(user[key])`

> Argument of type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'never'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Comment: The compiler doesn't understand in your code that the type of `user[key]` is *correlated* to the type of `userRules[key]`; this is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), which was recently fixed by [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  If your question is primarily about *why* this happens, then the answer has to do with ms/TS#30581.  If you are interested in refactoring to fix it, then [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WG570N) should work. Would you like me to write up an answer?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the detailed explanation and links. I study the topic. Yes, you can write an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, rather than worry about `Omit`ting a single key, let's define `IBaseSignupRequest` as

```
interface IBaseSignupRequest {
  login: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  agreePrivacy: boolean;
}
```

and then extend it to make `ISignupRequest`:

```
interface ISignupRequest extends IBaseSignupRequest {
  sendMarketingEmails: boolean;
}
```

This doesn't really change anything, but it does make it easier to talk about the code.

---

The main problem here is that the compiler does not realize that the type of the `userRules[key]` function is *correlated* to the type of the `user[key]` argument in such a way that the latter is always an acceptable input for the former.  Let's see what it thinks, by expanding it out into individual variables:

```
(key: keyof IBaseSignupRequest) => {
  const fn = userRules[key];
  // const fn: ((arg: string) => boolean) | ((arg: string) => boolean) |
  //  ((arg: string) => boolean) | ((arg: boolean) => boolean)
  const arg = user[key]
  // const arg: string | boolean
  return !fn(arg) // error!      
  // Argument of type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
}
```

So `userRules[key]` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of function types, some of which accept `string` and some of which accept `boolean`, and `user[key]` is a union of value types, some of which are `string` and some of which are `boolean`. These types are correct, but they are not specific enough.  The compiler treats this code as if it were:

```
(key1: keyof IBaseSignupRequest, key2: keyof IBaseSignupRequest) => {
  const fn = userRules[key1];
  // const fn: ((arg: string) => boolean) | ((arg: string) => boolean) |
  //  ((arg: string) => boolean) | ((arg: boolean) => boolean)
  const arg = user[key2]
  // const arg: string | boolean
  return !fn(arg) // error!      
  // Argument of type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
}
```

The types are exactly the same here.  `key1` and `key2` are both of the same type as `key`.  And now the compiler's warning should hopefully make more sense. You can't pick some random function from `userRules` and give it some random value from `user`.  What if you called `userRules["login"](user["agreePrivacy"])`?  The only way you could call a random function from `userRules` safely is if you passed it a value that would work no matter what.  That turns out to be the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the parameter types for the functions, as described in [the release notes for TS3.3 where calling unions of functions were first supported](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types).  The intersection `string & boolean` is reduced to `never`, which means the compiler thinks it is impossible to safely call `userRules[key]` no matter what.

But of course, `fn` and `arg` aren't *random* elements of `userRules` and `user`; they weren't indexed by `key1` and `key2` of the same type but possibly different values; they were indexed by `key`, the same variable.
The compiler doesn't track variable *identity*, though, only types.  So it doesn't see that `fn` and `arg` are *correlated*:  While separately they are of union types, together the pair `[fn, arg]` is of a type like `[(arg: string) => void, string] | [(arg: boolean) => void, boolean]`.

A while ago I opened [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) about the general lack of support for safely supporting such *correlated union types*.  Until TypeScript 4.6, there was no type-safe solution without writing redundant code.

---

With TypeScript 4.6, the fix at [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) allows people to write code like your `filter()` callback in a type safe way, as long as they're willing to refactor into a form the compiler can follow.  It looks like this:

First, you should express `IUserRules` in a way that depends *explicitly* on `IBaseSignupRequest`:

```
type IUserRules = {
  [P in keyof IBaseSignupRequest]: (arg: IBaseSignupRequest[P]) => boolean
}
```

Even though this is structurally equivalent to the previous version, now the compiler "expects" a correlation between `IUserRules` and `IBaseSignupRequest`.

And next, you should express the callback function as being [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `K extends keyof IBaseSignupRequest`.  When you do this, everything starts working:

```
<K extends keyof IBaseSignupRequest>(key: K) => {
  const fn = userRules[key];
  // const fn: IUserRules[K]
  const arg = user[key]
  // const arg:  IBaseSignupRequest[K]
  return !fn(arg) // okay
}
```

As you can see, both `fn` and `arg` stay generic in terms of `K`, and the compiler knows that the type of `fn`, `IUserRules[K]` is identical to `(arg: IBaseSignupRequest[K]) => void`.  And so `fn` will accept a value of the type of `arg`.

So that works. You can of course collapse it back to a simple arrow function with a returned expression:

```
<K extends keyof IBaseSignupRequest>(key: K) => !userRules[key](user[key]))
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICE4GcIGVgDmIArgA4BKEAjsRFmMgN4CwAUMsgDYD2BoAXMnpRQBANxsOEALZxgnQcNET2yUtiwB3blAAmisCJDjJyOASgQIABREA3RAE9BAI27dOEOCBUBfNmygkLCIKKj4RGSUNHQMEAAekCC6WGiYOBEkFNS09EymOMkAsnBQANYQYKIAorLyWK7unt5+AaxgjqRhAKo4UOTEnqkAvPmqANrWyKDIFY7cMGnYeIRZ0blgALqCABSlBIIYy5lRObGTmwCUyMMAfMhuHl4gbP6sbQjcIHnEfQNDh160H+dBuYw4PD4IF2kNA1zuyAAhIjYSAAHSeYxgAAWABpTOosFodPpkDtCcS9PD7siKdo9BiIFi8aYZHIFGS2fJqUjEVzOIzmfjVOZLDZ7E5dqKrDzpRBhb4VGxPt8GA5OMBdHBIECoAB5bikEZk0y-aCHdIrSLZGL0YWXQQAQSgUDgjgAPN5HPc7qYdnqXAArCAIMBouZYHZmqDXbDIZ2uj1zBbIDpdFPR26XUwcNEweTBHY7OaCZOLI4ZVanW1gHksVQcDgqvIwEBg6MgrDjOabFSNxsAegHyGbDFbuz2UAOQkMoh5j2aIGuAB8yZPp0pjPOms8VznB8O1-sDEYCNunt4V0ep40L0ubvcF7v902vnl9u2+t2II5Ni-kEOI5vgwx4zqeyCrk+3j-pYYDEFAbaIq267XIB0BQDoiL9hw-6Ac6BDENITIMCmaYoAA5JuBAQQ8O7eOR0ypCA3AgUSqxwC4niptwailHARHBMgpGdBRIAQHY0DkfuvjZg2yBorIpBFnMPI7PW2G8TipY-sKGlEUS5gQIIAAGAAkjBzL4jHTCA6qasZumNjJlxKqwo7IHZWo6n0eplG6YI7KafQWscVY2hsbAOvGLpup6IDeg+foBsGobhj+kbRrGqQJrFZapiJGZ9Fm+55gW0A7O6ADSyAJEkKSzD+KYVlaaxnPQtzFj+giVXW-7ua2n7AoMdDfr+fbYYB-XQmguqduMlV-nJr6qmYU6DVAo2LRpk3Aat05LJW1rrOcC0wZU8GIch+yocO3B+Y40myf2ClwEpnWOKp6nYeoWkNY4jn9vpWCGSZ5mWdZoCeQ5j0uW0cNubtnnahAuoBUF5oHS11YRawUU5R6Xo+rcSVBiGYYRlGfRZdFibunlZGFdAxVyaVnCFlVNWJEy9V5c1JzhbEHUlsgPUPkiHbDV2PaU9Am2XE9jYvW9Kli2p-4-di2n-f+QMg8gZkWT+VnAKkkNwBqujQ3JzmuWwQA)

Answer (score 0):

This is a really interesting issue.  It seems that TypeScript does not allow calling the function if any of the parameter types do not match at the same places to prevent unsafe code.  A minimal reproduction of this behavior is the following code:

```
declare const myFunc: ((a: boolean) => void) | ((b: string) => void);

myFunc(true); // Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

I am fairly sure the reason for this is because when TypeScript type checks parameters, it does the `&` to join the types.  However, when it tries to join the `boolean & string`, you will get `never` because those primitive types are impossible to have at the same time.  Overall, I think you're probably just best with typing the parameter with `any`.  However, I have came up with a partial solution by creating a new function type from a union of function types that has a rest parameter as a type union of all of the original function parameters and then a union for the return type of all of the functions.  Sadly, though, you lose type association on the return type by doing this as the parameter list is no longer joined with the return type.  Here's the code:

```
type UnsafeFuncUnion<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>;

declare const myFunc: UnsafeFuncUnion<((a: boolean) => void) | ((b: string) => string)>;

// no errors -- note the return type is `string | void`
myFunc(true);
myFunc("Hello");
```

And here is your code adjusted to use this method:

```
type UnsafeFuncUnion<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>;

interface ISignupRequest {
  login: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  agreePrivacy: boolean;
  sendMarketingEmails: boolean;
}

interface IUserRules {
  login: (login: string) => boolean;
  password: (password: string) => boolean;
  email: (email: string) => boolean;
  agreePrivacy: (agree: boolean) => boolean;
}

const userRules: IUserRules = {
  login: (login) => !!login.length,
  password: (password) => !!password.length,
  email: (email) => !!email.length,
  agreePrivacy: (agree) => agree,
};

const validateUser = (
  user: Omit<ISignupRequest, "sendMarketingEmails">,
): Array<any> =>
  (Object.keys(user) as Array<keyof typeof user>)
    .filter((key) => !(userRules[key] as UnsafeFuncUnion<IUserRules[keyof IUserRules]>)(user[key]))
    .map((key) => ({
      path: key,
      message: `${key} is invalid`,
    }));
```